# How to manage music playing app Android

Tags: android, audio-player, android-music-player

The question is: How to manage (for example stop, start) music in music players like Tidal or Spotify from my app.
For example when i click button in my app the music from tidal on my phone stops plaing. 
Thanks! John

Comment: There might be a better way of asking this question because i didn't get it\

Comment: if you are asking for guide just google it. Check here for example: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

For loose control, target intents with [`ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON) directly at the broadcastreceiver of the app you want to stop. This allows commands which have an associated key event.

For tight control, use [`MediaSessionManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSessionManager.html). This allows a maximum of control, but requires an active `NotificationListener`.